# How to use background services in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui, background-service

I'm trying to implement background services for an application built in in .NET MAUI but it fails if use the below service technique. Is there any other implementation for this ?
https://github.com/jfversluis/XFBackgroundLocationSample

https://github.com/jfversluis/XFBackgroundLocationSample
I tried the code is above github but I'm unable to trigger a location service and call an API even when the app is in background. Also is there any implementation for iOS too. I can't find any background services solution for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Background Service in MAUI the suggestion is to use [Shiny.NET](https://shinylib.net/). With this you can make location services to work, but you must make sure to ask permission and make sure you have the ability to use location on that device.

For IOS you can read about this here [Configuring your app to use location services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/configuring_your_app_to_use_location_services)

For Android you read about this here [Build location-aware apps](https://developer.android.com/training/location)

Comment: Can I use this and send the location to API. I can see the package can take the location when app is in background but how can use API when the app is in background. Maui background services to trigger API when app is in background is not working properly.

Comment: @SANSHEVA You cannot do what you're looking for anymore, the best you can do is create a foreground service on Android and a Background Task on iOS and as long as they are active they will be able to send the location to you. Also if you somehow make the user grant you background permissions and  they let you run their app permanently in the background the app would probably get rejected unless you have a solid reason for it. And it's impossible to do on iOS because it's an OS restriction